# Filter at least one null on records when select data

Tags: mysql

How to filter null values ​​from a query as follows:

```
mysql> 

    SELECT  pc.shipment_id,
            c.container_serial_number 
    FROM prospect_container pc  

    LEFT JOIN container c ON 
    pc.id = c.prospect_container_id; 
+-------------+-------------------------+
| shipment_id | container_serial_number |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           4 | 7987493                 |
|           4 | NULL                    |
|           5 | NULL                    |
|           5 | NULL                    |
|           6 | NULL                    |
+-------------+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please see shipment_id = 4;

As you can see there are two records.
One record is null and another record = 7987493.
As a rule, if there is already a value, then the record may not be included in the result.

The results to be achieved:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| shipment_id | container_serial_number |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           5 | NULL                    |
|           6 | NULL                    |
+-------------+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  pc.shipment_id,
        NULL container_serial_number 
FROM prospect_container pc  
LEFT JOIN container c ON pc.id = c.prospect_container_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING MAX(c.container_serial_number) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
SELECT a.shipment_id
     , a.container_serial_number
  FROM (
       SELECT pc.shipment_id
            , c.container_serial_number 
         FROM prospect_container pc  
         LEFT JOIN container c 
           ON pc.id = c.prospect_container_id
        GROUP BY pc.shipment_id
            , c.container_serial_number
      ) AS a
  GROUP BY a.shipment_id
 HAVING COUNT(a.shipment_id) = 1 
 ;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it